# How to integrate different variables into one function?

Tags: python, function, variables

I want to make this code more efficient by adding functions. The tasks in the if statements are practically the same - only the variable changes. However, I am not sure how to change the list depending on the user choice for the function. Does anyone know a way to do this?

```
total = 0
A1 = ["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50]
B1 = ["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200]
C1 = ["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]

print(A1[0:2])
print(B1[0:2])
print(C1[0:2])

while True:
    choice = (input("What would you like?")).upper()
    quantity = float(input("How many would you like?"))

    if choice == "BIG MAC":
        if quantity > A1[2]:
            print("There is not enough stock!")
            pass
        else:
            total += A1[1]*quantity
            A1[2] -= quantity

    elif choice == "LARGE FRIES":
        if quantity > B1[2]:
            print("There is not enough stock!")
            pass
        else:
            total += B1[1]*quantity
            B1[2] -= quantity

    elif choice == "VEGETARIAN BURGER":
        if quantity > C1[2]:
            print("There is not enough stock!")
            pass
        else:
            total += C1[1]*quantity
            C1[2] -= quantity
    more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
    if more_items == "yes":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Thank you for ordering!\n"
      "Your total cost is:", total)
```

Comment: you can pass the list as an argument to your function

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this, as I am not quite sure? @Fabricator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your order choices into a 2D list, it makes it easier to index things.

```
def process_choice(quantity,stock,price,total):
    if quantity > stock:
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += price*quantity
        stock -= quantity
    return total, stock        


total = 0    
A = [["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50],["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200],["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]]

print(A[0])
print(A[1])
print(A[2])

while True:
    choice = (input("What would you like?")).upper()
    quantity = float(input("How many would you like?"))

    choices = [A[0][0].upper(),A[1][0].upper(),A[2][0].upper()]
    idx = choices.index(choice)

    total, A[idx][2] = process_choice(quantity,A[idx][2],A[idx][1],total)

    more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
    if more_items == "yes":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Thank you for ordering!")
print("Your total cost is:", total)
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting your list of items to a dict would be helpful and would reduce having to state all of the if - elif -else statements

```
total = 0

item_dict = {
"BIG MAC": [float(2.50), 50],
"LARGE FRIES": [float(0.50), 200],
"VEGETARIAN BURGER": [float(1.00), 20]}

def order_adder(menu_item, quantity, total):
    try:
        if item_dict[menu_item][1] - quantity < 0:
            print("There is not enough stock!")
        else:
            item_dict[menu_item][1] = item_dict[menu_item][1] - quantity
            total += item_dict[menu_item][0]*quantity
    except(KeyError):
        print("We don't sell that item")
    return total

while True:
    choice = (input("What would you like?")).upper()
    quantity = float(input("How many would you like?"))

    total = order_adder(choice, quantity, total)

    more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
    if more_items == "yes":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Thank you for ordering!\n"
      "Your total cost is:", total)
```

Comment: you should use `item_dict.get()` to access key, it's unsafe to trust user input, he will surely try to ask some whiskey once

Comment: @PRMoureu that's just swapping a `KeyError` with a `TypeError`.

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah, unless you give some fallback value to prevent this, or test  `item_dict.get(choice)`  before calling `order_adder`

Comment: Edited to avoid KeyErrors

Comment: @Peter For the specific task I was doing, it specified that I had to use lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a function with the common functionality and just pass different parameters for each case.

**The function:**

```
def processOrder(quantity, stock, total):
    if quantity > stock[2]:
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += stock[1] * quantity
        stock[2] -= quantity
```

**The whole program:**

```
def processOrder(quantity, stock, total):
    if quantity > stock[2]:
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += stock[1] * quantity
        stock[2] -= quantity

total = 0
A1 = ["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50]
B1 = ["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200]
C1 = ["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]

print(A1[0:2])
print(B1[0:2])
print(C1[0:2])

while True:
    choice = (input("What would you like?")).upper()
    quantity = float(input("How many would you like?"))

      more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
    if more_items == "yes":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Thank you for ordering!\n"
      "Your total cost is:", total)
 if choice == "BIG MAC":
        processOrder(quantity, A1, total)

    elif choice == "LARGE FRIES":
        processOrder(quantity, B1, total)

    elif choice == "VEGETARIAN BURGER":
        processOrder(quantity, C1, total)
```

Comment: That would always use `A1`, also for large fries and vegetarian burgers.

Comment: I just fixed it it is now passing the correct list for all of them

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking DobromirM's answer:

```
total = 0
def processOrder(quantity, stock):
    global total
    if quantity > stock[2]:
        print(quantity, stock[1])
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += stock[1] * quantity
        stock[2] -= quantity

A1 = ["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50]
B1 = ["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200]
C1 = ["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]

print(A1[0:2])
print(B1[0:2])
print(C1[0:2])

while True:
    choice = (input("What would you like?")).upper()
    quantity = float(input("How many would you like?"))
    if choice == "BIG MAC":
        processOrder(quantity, A1)
    elif choice == "LARGE FRIES":
        processOrder(quantity, B1)
    elif choice == "VEGETARIAN BURGER":
        processOrder(quantity, C1)
    more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
    if more_items == "yes":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("Thank you for ordering!\nYour total cost is:", total)
```